# How to use the dedicated GPU instead of Intel on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, 17.10, radeon

My current status is:

```
lucian@0x90:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PMC
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pmc_core
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0767
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev c3)
    Subsystem: Dell Radeon R7 M445
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

How can I use Radeon R7 M445 as my graphic card when I do not have additional drivers or available AMD proprietary drivers?